# IOS - Can Smack 4.2.0 library be used for IOS client to connect to Openfire Server?

Tags: ios, smack

Can you please let me know if Smack library can be used in a iOS client app to connect to an Openfire chat server ? Appreciate any starting leads you could give.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to github: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

It is the XMPP framework in Objective-C and is suitable for Mac and iOS development communities.